# Run a javascript when app is terminated

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

Im using the local-notafication plug in -
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/blob/master/README.md#retrieve-the-ids-from-all-currently-scheduled-local-notifications

I'm scheduling a notification and this works but I want to be able to schedule a notification that only is displayed every second week and  one that only are displayed every third week as well, does anybody have any pointers for how I can't get this to work?

```
var now = new Date().getTime(),
_60_seconds_from_now = new Date(now + 120*1000);
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
                                     id:      28,
                                     title:   'Reminder',
                                     message: 'Dont forget to buy some flowers.',
                                     repeat:  'weekly',
```

I want to be able to the repeat to every second week and every third week as well as weekly.

```
                                     date:    _60_seconds_from_now
                                     });
```

this is in the APPLocalNotification.m file

```
#ifdef NSCalendarUnitHour
[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSCalendarUnitSecond] forKey:@"secondly"];
[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSCalendarUnitMinute] forKey:@"minutely"];
[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSCalendarUnitHour] forKey:@"hourly"];
[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSCalendarUnitDay] forKey:@"daily"];
[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSWeekCalendarUnit] forKey:@"weekly"];
[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSCalendarUnitMonth] forKey:@"monthly"];
[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSCalendarUnitYear] forKey:@"yearly"];
#else
[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSSecondCalendarUnit] forKey:@"secondly"];
[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSMinuteCalendarUnit] forKey:@"minutely"];
[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSHourCalendarUnit] forKey:@"hourly"];
[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSDayCalendarUnit] forKey:@"daily"];
[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSWeekCalendarUnit] forKey:@"weekly"];
[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSMonthCalendarUnit] forKey:@"monthly"];
[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSYearCalendarUnit] forKey:@"yearly"];
#endif

[repeatDict setObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSEraCalendarUnit] forKey:@""];

return repeatDict;
```

}

is it possible to add new keys? And how would they look in that case?

Answer (score 0):

`repeat:  'weekly'` means it will keep repeating itself in every week. So it will repeat itself in the first week, then in second week. With your code first time notification will be given exactly after 2 minutes. Then it will repeat itself again exactly same time in next week. Then in the week after that in same time. And so on......

Is this you need to know? A short suggestion: may be you can ask this question (how to add that option) on the issue page of that plugin.

Comment: sorry, i think my formulation was a bit of, I want to set a reminder every third week, so this one is not suppose to display weekly